# magento 2 when sales api override error

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2, rest-api, magento2-api

We are getting the following error when sales order data override to custom module

```
"message": "Missing required argument $resourceClassName of Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata.",
```

can anyone help me on this issue

[image]

Comment: Can you post code where you are overriding sales API in your module. Just paste your XML files here.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Ewall\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" type="Ewall\Sales\Model\OrderRepository"/>
    <type name="Ewall\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="orderMetadata" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="resourceClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
            <argument name="modelClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

I missed

```
<virtualType name="orderMetadata" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="resourceClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
                <argument name="modelClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\Order</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
```

Comment: this help me too, when get same error... thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: it really help me to solve same problem